# Laravel 5.6 MySQL Server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**Background**

I have a basic Laravel application that was working just fine. I ran a `php artisan make:auth` on it, migrated, registered a new user and was able to login and view the home.blade.php. I'm using **valet** to serve the site, and have parked it in the directory.

I'm not using Homestead, just using my local machine.

**What caused the issue**

I ran a `brew update / brew upgrade`, and now am unable to login to the application at all.

**Expected outcome**

Login to the application and view the home.blade.php

**Errors being thrown**

`PDOException (2006)
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away` shows in the browser.

`PDOException(code: 0): PDO::__construct(): Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2 auth: 109` shows up in the Laravel logs.

I *suspect* it has something to do with user privileges with MySQL, although I'm just at a stand-still here, so I thought I'd toss it out to the Obi-Wan's of the computer world.

**What works**

I can still view the welcome.blade.php in the browser, and pinging the server returns a response, so that works.

I can login to MySQL through the terminal as root no problem.

`mysql -u root -p`

```
mysql> SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| jason            | %         |
| jason            | localhost |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My database exists

```
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------------+
| Tables_in_digitalchef |
+-----------------------+
| migrations            |
| model_has_permissions |
| model_has_roles       |
| orders                |
| password_resets       |
| permissions           |
| role_has_permissions  |
| roles                 |
| users                 |
+-----------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

**My Setup**

PHP Version

```
jason@Jasons-MacBook-Air:~/Desktop/websites$ php -v
PHP 7.2.8 (cli) (built: Jul 19 2018 12:15:24) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.8, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Nginx Version

```
jason@Jasons-MacBook-Air:~/Desktop/websites$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.15.3
```

MySQL Version

```
jason@Jasons-MacBook-Air:~$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.12 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)
```

Valet Version

```
Laravel Valet 2.0.9
```

$PATH

```
jason@Jasons-MacBook-Air:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/opt/mysql@8.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/jason/.composer/vendor/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

**EDIT - Updated this, still no luck**
The contents of my **/etc/my.cnf:**

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 500M
wait_timeout = 58800
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql-ssl/server-key.pem
```

My **.env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:/rKbcwAqCwbNt9XNBZq1jzvRzi7K4Jdch3k5/OtUgis=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=digitalchef
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

My **database.php**

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Database Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
    | to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
    | you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Database Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
    | Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
    | supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
    |
    |
    | All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
    | so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
    | choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],

        'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Migration Repository Table
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
    | your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
    | the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
    |
    */

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
    */

    'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],

];
```

**Recent entries in the log**

```
[2018-09-10 18:15:26] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 2006): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away at /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68, PDOException(code: 0): PDO::__construct(): Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2 auth: 109 at /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68)
[stacktrace]
#0 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(68): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'root', Array)
#1 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(98): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'root', Array)
#2 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(48): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection(Object(PDOException), 'mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'root', Array)
#3 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=127....', Array, Array)
#4 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(182): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#5 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#6 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(915): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#7 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(248): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdo()
#8 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(234): Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager->refreshPdoConnections('mysql')
#9 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php(168): Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager->reconnect('mysql')
#10 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection))
#11 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(753): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection))
#12 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(735): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->reconnect()
#13 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(717): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException), 'select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#14 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(627): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->handleQueryException(Object(Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException), 'select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#15 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(333): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#16 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1963): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select * from `...', Array, true)
#17 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1951): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#18 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(2435): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}()
#19 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1952): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->onceWithColumns(Array, Object(Closure))
#20 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(481): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get(Array)
#21 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(465): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getModels(Array)
#22 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php(77): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->get(Array)
#23 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php(128): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->first()
#24 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php(352): Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider->retrieveByCredentials(Array)
#25 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php(79): Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard->attempt(Array, false)
#26 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php(44): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\LoginController->attemptLogin(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\LoginController->login(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#28 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#29 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('login', Array)
#30 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(212): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\Auth\\LoginController), 'login')
#31 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(169): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#32 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(665): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#33 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php(24): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): App\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#36 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#39 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(68): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#41 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#42 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#44 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#45 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#47 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#48 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#50 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#51 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#53 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#54 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#56 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(667): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#57 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(642): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#58 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(608): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#59 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(597): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#60 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#61 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#62 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#63 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#64 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#65 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#66 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#67 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#68 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#69 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#70 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#71 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#72 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#73 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#74 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(62): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#75 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#76 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#77 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#78 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#79 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#80 /Users/jason/Desktop/websites/restaurant/digitalchef/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#81 /Users/jason/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php(147): require('/Users/jason/De...')
#82 {main}
"}
```

**What I've been trying:**

- `mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON digitalchef.* TO 'root'@'localhost';`
  but no dice.
- I've restarted nginx, php, mysql.
- I looked at this answer: [Set modes in the database.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23961)
- And tried running through these steps: [Create a new user and grant privileges](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1392)
- I've been reading up here [PHP Bug 76651](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76651) and it seems like it's an issue
  with PHP 7.2.8.

I'd prefer not to have to roll-back to 7.2.7, but if that's the only option then I guess I'm between a rock and a hard place and don't have any choice.

Any assistance would be great. If you need some more information about anything, just ask away and I'll answer. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Possibly MySQL was running with ssl enabled, and now is not. (Based entirely on that caching sha log message.)

Comment: Not an apple user here, so I just like to ask the obligatory _Did you turn it off and on again already?_ question (talking about the whole computer).

Comment: I don't see any wait_timeout directive setting in your my.cnf configuration.

Comment: @Namoshek absolutely! That might have been one of the issues, tbh. I had been delaying the MacOS High Sierra update to **10.13.6 (17G65)** and it went through when I restarted

Comment: This should fix it. https://zeshankhattak.com/posts/pdo-construct-unexpected-server-respose-while-doing-caching-sha2-auth-109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this sorted out! **Woohoo!** Thank you again to everyone for all of the advice, I really appreciated the assistance.

**How I Resolved:**

Digging deeper into this, I noticed that I had 2 versions of MySQL installed - 5.7 & 8.0.

- **I uninstalled mysql@5.7 via homebrew**

  - `brew uninstall mysql@5.7`
- **Linked the correct version**

  - `brew link mysql@8.0`
- **I updated my $PATH**

  - `sudo nano ~/.bash_profile`
  - And added the following line in place of the 5.7:
  - `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@8.0/bin:$PATH"`
- **I followed [@poohbear 's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467762/laravel-migration-stalls-and-doesnt-do-anything/51560959) about altering the mysql user**
- Then, I truncated the user table on the Laravel database from the mysql prompt

  - `mysql -u root -p`
  - `mysql> USE digitalchef;`
  - `mysql> TRUNCATE TABLE users;`

I don't know if it accomplished anything after the fact, but I made sure to run a `php artisan config:cache` afterwards, just for good measure.

Hopefully this helps someone out who is struggling with this! Thank you all again for the support, and @poohbear deserves mad credit for his answer.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me. I used the following command to update my password with new authentication plugin. You can use MySQL 8 now. Have fun.

```
ALTER USER `username`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
```

If above doesn't work use this instead.

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Answer (score 1):

if the msyql client is normal ,only the php7 script has problem,
you can check the php.ini (mysqlnd.net_read_timeout)

Comment: Can elaborate in which circumstances this is fix is better than the accepted answer? How did you change the value?

Answer (score 0):

Installing mysql and uninstalling mysql/maria db won't fix the issue. This can happen for several reasons.

This generally indicates MySQL server connectivity issues or timeouts.

You can adjust settings in `my.cnf` by adjusting `wait_timeout` and `max_allowed_packet`.

Try setting it to something higher, keep adjusting the settings until you get it right. Make sure you restart mysql after you've made these changes.

```
wait_timeout = 28800

max_allowed_packet = 8M
```

Here is a good explanation on what you need to change

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! I've tried editing the **my.cnf** and added in the wait_timeout as you suggested, but it's still hanging and throwing the `"PDO::__construct(): Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2 auth: 109"` error.

Comment: can you log into mysql via command line? can you even start mysqld without issues? you should resolved mysql issues via command line then you can move on with your programming.

Comment: Yes, I can log into mysql via the terminal @unixmiah - I made a note of that in my post, along with some of the output. I can run queries without issue. I think the issue lies somewhere in the PHP 7.2.8 and MySQL 8.0

Answer (score -1):

You probably restarted mysql already, but try doing it if not

In case it doesn't work try uninstalling it:

```
brew uninstall mysql
```

And installing mariadb, it'll work similar to mysql:

```
brew install mariadb
```

Then you can still do `mysql -uroot` to manage your databases

Comment: That is a pretty bold move, no matter how feature compatible MySQL and Maria are. Do you have specific  reasons to believe this move will specifically address the OP?

Comment: Because I went through it a couple of weeks ago when updating mysql, the new version stopped working and giving me the same error he is having and some others. I'm not saying it's the only solution but for me it was the first one that worked.